# Export struct with 2 Array from C++ into C#

Tags: arrays, string, dllimport

Help

In C++

```
    #pragma pack(push,1) 
typedef struct SIGMPGroup{
  int temp;
  char name[50]; //name of group
  int port; 
  char addr[50]; //network address "229."
  //int ttl;          //
  //int loop;         // 0 - no loop back, 1 - loop back

  SIGMPGroup():
  temp(0),
  port(0)
  //ttl(-1),
  //loop(0)
  {}
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

C#

```
public static SIGMPGroup DTIGMPGroup = new SIGMPGroup { temp = 56, name = "Example",port = 4000 };
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 108)]
   public struct SIGMPGroup{
     [FieldOffset(0)] 
     public int temp;
     [ FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst=50)]
     public string name; //name of group
     [FieldOffset(54)]
     public int port;

     [FieldOffset(58), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
     public string addr;

   }

    [DllImport(Eth_DLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void Leave(ref SIGMPGroup data);

   ImportFunctionEth.Leave(ref ImportFunctionEth.DTIGMPGroup);
```

After Run I have Error :
Could not load type "SIGMPGroup" from the assembly "ConsoleApplication1, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null", because it contains an object field at offset 58 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped field does not represent an object.

If code

```
 [FieldOffset(58), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
 public string addr;
```

delete , All work. Why ?

Work only like this

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
   public struct SIGMPGroup{

     public int temp;
     [  MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst=50)]
     public string name; //name of group

     public int port;

     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
     public string addr;

   }
```

Comment: Looks like standard marshalling for unaligned string is not allowed. I would declare the only byte[] member in this struct with SizeConst = 108 and make all conversion stuff manually, for example, by using BitConverter class, String(sbyte*) constructor etc.

Comment: if use as example        [ FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=50)]
         public char[] name; i have Error: Failed to pack type, since the length of an embedded array instance does not match the length declared in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure what to make of this error, the CLR appears to want to keep the struct blittable for some mysterious reason.  It certainly is not, the strings spoil that.  Ultimately the error is caused by the *port* field, it is misaligned at that violates the .NET memory model's promise that updates for simple types like *int* are atomic.  Its offset is pushed to 56 and that overlaps the 2nd string.

StructLayout.Explicit can be quirky and you are helping to much.  Simply solved by not helping:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SIGMPGroup {
    public int temp;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string name; //name of group
    public int port;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string addr;
}

...
Debug.Assert(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGMPGroup) == 108);   // fine
```